# How does einsum interact with numpy broadcasting?

Tags: numpy, numpy-einsum

Consider ndarrays `x0=np.ones((3,3))` and `y0`, which has `y0.shape` either (3,3) or (1,3). I want a single einsum command that computes the dot products of the rows of these two arrays; in the case that `y0.shape` is `(1,3)`, I want broadcasting over the first dimension of `y0`. I tried
`np.einsum('ij,ij->i',x0,y0)` but this gives

`ValueError: ("Size of label '%s' for operand %d does not match previous terms.", 'i', 1)`

Is there a way to do this in einsum? It appears that einsum's interaction with numpy broadcasting is somewhat limited in this application: `x0 + y0` broadcasts the first dimension when the shape of y0 is (1,3), but the einsum call above doesn't function as I expected.

Comment: This is a known `einsum` bug, see [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/10352).